# Combination chart with negative and positive values in R, axis manipulation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot it R that is suppose to show loss and volume. I have tried the below and I am not able to figure out why the red line is not showing up and why the secondary axis "volume" is inverse.

The axis on the left has values ranging from -10 to -40 and the axis on the right volume has values ranging from 600 to 800.

[image: Plot]

```
Plot <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = floor_date(WeekEnding, unit = "week"))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = AverageUnitsLoss), size = 1.5, color="red", group = 1) +
  geom_col(aes(y = UnitVolume/-20), size = 2, color = "darkblue", fill = "white", group = 2)+
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 week', date_labels = '%Y-%m-%d', expand = c(.01, .01)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*-20, name = "Volume"))+
  xlab("Weekending")
```

Comment: Please `dput(head(Data,40))` and paste the result in the question in order to help you!

Comment: You put the bars on top of the line, since in **ggplot2** "layers" are added to the plot in the order you list them.  Put `geom_line()` after `geom_col()` to put the line on top.

Comment: As for the axis reversal, you can probably use `scale_y_reverse` in place of `scale_y_continuous` to fix that.  It will reverse both axes.

Comment: The red line is visible, it's just shown *behind* the bars